# iOS simulator "Settings" app crashes

Tags: ios

The settings app crashes in iOS simulator, running iOS 6.0, retina 4 inch. Anyone noticed this? Any workaround?

Comment: Works fine for me. Does it also crashes when using different "hardware"?

Comment: It's working for me, does it work with the rest of the devices? Reset the simulator, or reinstall XCode or the simulator is that doesn't work.

Comment: It started working again when switching to 3.5 inch screen. Back to 4 and it crashes. I even reset all the contents but the problem is still there. Anyway, I just rarely use the simulator anyway but it seems that it's very flakey at this point.